# local variable in object initializers

Tags: javascript, variables, object, local, initializer

The question is: Is it possible to create a structure like the folowing using object initializers in JavaScript?

```
var human = new function (years) {
    var age = years;
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        age: {
            enumerable:true,
            get: function () {
                return age;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                if( typeof value != 'number') throw 'Age must be a number';
                age = value;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What I tried to do:

```
var years = 0;
var human = {
    _age: years,
    get age () {
        return this._age;
    },
    set age (value) {
        if( typeof value != 'number') throw 'Age must be a number';
        this._age = value;
    }
}
```

This example is more intuitive and "friendly" (for me at least), but I need that "_age" was local as it is in the previous example.

Is it possible to make local variables in object initializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
    function myObject(){
      var privateVar = 'default';

      this.setPrivateVar = function(val){
        privateVar = val;
      }

      this.getPrivateVar= function(){
        return privateVar;
      }

    }

var obj = new myObject();
alert(obj.privateVar); //undefined
alert(obj.getPrivateVar()) // default
```

Another example:

```
   function myObject(){
       var privatVariable = 'default';
       return {
           getVal : function(){
                return privatVariable;
           }
       }
   }

var obj = myObject();
```

Comment: your example is good, but it's a C++ like aproach, i would like to use an pure JavaScript aproach using an object initializer

Comment: I like the second example, but I am still searching for something more easy to use ;)

Comment: It is written in JavaScript so it is a JavaScript approach :)